# Merge few lines into one line in JAVA

Tags: java, csv, merge, hashmap, bufferedreader

On the beginning, I'd like to say that i'm total n00bie in JAVA, i'm starting to learn JAVA few weeks ago... and I have quite an interesting task ahead of me...

So let's go to the point :D

I must transform *.csv file to *.csv file :)

I have file which looks something like this:

```
aaaaa;bbbbb;ccccc;ddddd;eeeee;fffff;ggggg <- header of file
uuuuu;wwwww; 101 ;xxxxx;yyyyy;  01 ; 001
uuuuu;wwwww; 101 ;xxxxx;yyyyy;  01 ; 002
uuuuu;wwwww; 102 ;xxxxx;yyyyy;  02 ; 001
uuuuu;wwwww; 102 ;xxxxx;yyyyy;  02 ; 002
```

Now I want to merge this lines to one line, it should be looks like that:

```
uuuuu;wwwww;xxxxx;yyyyy;101;102;01;001;002;02;001;002
```

As u can see 4 columns are have the same data, 3 columns are always have different data

For now I have only this... as u can see the code is very poor ^^ that's because i'm still learning :D

```
import java.io.*;

public class ReadFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            String path = "file.csv";
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(path);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] cols = line.split(";");

                String tmp = new String();
                for(int i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
                    tmp += ";";
                    tmp = tmp + cols[i];
                }
                System.out.println(tmp);
 }
            bufferedReader.close();

            } catch(FileNotFoundException e)    {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)  {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

I tried to do this using HashMap but with no result, maybe I'm doing something wrong (it is very possible), I'm still looking for something which will help me to solve this somehow ;)
I will be grateful for any tips how can I do this or maybe it is not possible to do this ;D
I was looking for a similar topic but it failed :/ Today I found something like opencsv, maybe this will help me somehow maybe....

Comment: Should could work if the file have verities of data or do you need code working only for the test sample you have? Lets say data have uuuuu;wwwww; 101 ;xxxxx;yyyyy;  01 ; 001 and aaaa;bbbb; 101 ;cccc;ddd;  01 ; 001, then do you required to have two lines of output in output csv file?

Comment: It's a sample of how looks a file, I can't send real data :) of course it is possible that there will be single lines in a file, in case of this the best solution I think will be create a modified line like this one which I show you in topic, so yes it should be two lines in output because you show 2 different lines